# How to implement .indexof for an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string-matching

How can I simplify below code? How can I get rid of the if statements? I want to highlight some lines in ajax response. Right now I have two strings to compare = two ifs. This number will increase so I am thinking of doing this some other way - using an array of the strings that needs to be highlighted in case the string is part of data_array element.

I prefer a solution in javascript only but jQuery is ok too.

```
    data_array=data.split('<BR>');
    for(var i=0, len=data_array.length; i < len; i++){
        if (data_array[i].indexOf('Conflict discovered') >= 0){
            data_array[i]="<span class='red'>"+data_array[i]+"</span>";
        }   
        if (data_array[i].indexOf('Syntax error') >= 0){
            data_array[i]="<span class='red'>"+data_array[i]+"</span>";
        }   
    }
    data=data_array.join('<BR>');
```

Comment: @Ibu, You're why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Ibu javascript = browser. jQuery = 32KB

Comment: @ibu - jquery != javascript.  "but jQuery is ok too" implies solutions utilizing jQuery methods are acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add more elements to the array as desired :)

```
data.replace( /<br>/ig, '\n' ).replace(
    new RegExp( '^(.*(?:' + [
          'Conflict discovered'
        , 'Syntax error'
    ].join( '|' ) + ').*)$', 'gm' )
, '<span class="red">$1</span>' ).replace( /\n/g, '<br>' );
```

explanation:

- replace `<br>` tags with line breaks
- make a regexp: `^(.*(?:Conflict discovered|Syntax error).*)$`
- surround matches with `<span class="red">` ... `</span>`
- turn line breaks back in to `<br>` tags

Comment: Will this `span` the text from an array or the whole lot between `<br>`'s?

Comment: Yes, it was desired. :-) But I couldn't figure it out from the code by myself. So I asked.

Comment: yeah, that's what the `^(.* ... .*)$` is for, to match the whole line

Comment: Why did you have to replace <br> with new lines? I guess I can replace ['Conflict discovered' ] with a variable name, can't I.

Comment: because the `^` and `$` match against beginning and end of lines.  Without it, I'd need to overly complicate the regex to find entire lines between `<br>` tags.  Yes, you can replace the `[ ... ]` with a variable.  And yes, it's "one line" if that matters

Comment: I like your solution the best but it doesn't work for me with data `sudo svn merge -r %revision-1%:%revision% svn+ssh://radek@repository.edumate.com.au/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/trunk /srv/www/htdocs/mm-codebases/radek/test4.0.3/ 2>&1<BR>svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '%revision-1%:%revision%'`

Comment: what?  What does an svn merge issue have to do with that code?

Comment: works for me.  splits back: `sudo svn merge -r %revision-1%:%revision% svn+ssh://radek@repository.edumate.com.au/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/trunk /srv/www/htdocs/mm-codebases/radek/test4.0.3/ 2>&1<br><span class="red">svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '%revision-1%:%revision%'</span>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18084/discussion-between-radek-and-cwolves)

Comment: Works smoothly, I thought that above code modifies the variable data. Thank you. PS great explanation. PS2 I like one liners

Comment: Regexps - if they need explaining, they're probably unmaintainable by the programmer who comes along next.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot -- that's what comments are for.  And if you seriously thing a comment that simply says `regex is: ^(.*(?:A|B).*)$` is too complicated then you need better devs, otherwise you're just arguing against all regex's, which is crazy :)

Comment: Of course, plenty of people have seen crazy regex's, but that's not a reason to not use them.  If they're complicated, they deserve simple comments explaining them, but they shouldn't not be used

Comment: Moreover, it's not me who thought an explanation was necessary.

Comment: yeah, but people should learn to use regexes :)  Most people won't understand the `(?:`, but I'm not going to not use it because of that

Answer (score 3):

Why not add another `for` loop?

```
data_array=data.split('<BR>');

var stringsToFind = ['Conflict discovered', 'Syntax error'];

for (var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < stringsToFind.length; j++) {

        var currItem = data_array[i];

        if (currItem.indexOf(stringsToFind[j]) >= 0) {

            data_array[i]='<span class="red">' + currItem + '</span>';
        }
    }  
}

data = data_array.join('<BR>');
```

**jQuery** (note, may be slower, and I haven't tested this yet)

```
data_array=data.split('<BR>');

var stringsToFind = ['Conflict discovered', 'Syntax error'];

$.each(data_array, function(i, item) {
    $.each(stringsToFind, function(j, s) {
        if (item.indexOf(s) >= 0) {
            data_array[i]='<span class="red">' + item + '</span>';
        }
    }
});

data = data_array.join('<BR>');
```

Comment: In addition to that, I would use jQuery.each which is a nicer form of iteration.

Comment: @Anderson Silva: True, but this would be the pure javascript solution if Radek doesn't want the jQuery library.

Comment: Could you add sample of `.each` to you answer so I'll accept it?

Comment: @Radek Check my answer which doesn't use any loops

Comment: Yes, but I like yours the best. Sorry @Laurence.

Comment: No problem, I like @cwolves's regex too. It's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data_array = data.split('<BR>');
var errMsgs = ['Conflict discovered', 'Syntax error'];
data_array = data_array.map(function(data_rec) {
    var isAnError = errMsgs.some(function (errMsg) {
        return data_rec.indexOf(errMsg) >= 0;
    });
    if (isAnError) {
        return "<span class='red'>" + data_rec + '</span>';
    } else {
        return data_rec;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 I didn't even know about `some`. This is a really good solution, @Insidi0us

Comment: `some()` is pretty new, see here for a JS equivalent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility

Comment: Oh, but you should note that this is IE9 and all modern browsers only, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emujap/1/edit)*

```
var highlightWords = ['Conflict discovered', 'Syntax error', 'Simply cool'];

for(i=0; i<highlightWords.length; i++){
  var regex = new RegExp(highlightWords[i],'ig');
  data= data.replace( regex, '<span class="red">'+ highlightWords[i] +'</span>');
}

$('div').html( data );
```

---

### *[jsBin demo 2 all line highlight](http://jsbin.com/emujap/2/edit)*

```
var words = ['Conflict discovered', 'Syntax error', 'Strange'];
var data_array=data.split('<BR>');

for(n=0;n<words.length;n++){
  for(i=0; i<data_array.length; i++){
      if (data_array[i].indexOf( words[n] ) >= 0){
           data_array[i]="<span class='red'>"+data_array[i]+"</span>";
      }   
  }
  data = data_array.join('<BR>');
}

$('div').html( data );
```

Comment: Your code highlights the (error) string only. Mine the whole line defined from <br> to <br>. I like it though. I learnt something new.

Comment: I like your solution very much too. Actually it is probably easier to read than @cwolves' one.

Comment: @Radek Thanks! I'm glad was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
data_array=data.split('<BR>');
for(var i=0, len=data_array.length; i < len; i++){
    var dai = data_array[i];
    if (dai.indexOf('Conflict discovered') >= 0 || dai.indexOf('Syntax error') >= 0){
        data_array[i] = "<span class='red'>"+dai+"</span>";
    }   
}
data=data_array.join('<BR>');
```

Comment: Yes :-) but wouldn't be easier to have an array that I modify instead of introducing new `if` or `or`? I have one config file that I would like such array to have in.

Comment: @Radek, check out .map and .forEach